# How to expose votings (such as in rate or voting api) to views?

Tags: 7, views, rating

To avoid the obvious misunderstandings: I know how to display the rate widget in a view, including the vote cast by the user, the average, sum etc. This is not what I'm looking for.

I want a view whose rows are the individual votes cast, with fields containing the information who cast the vote and what it was cast on and how much the rating was. When I create a new view, I can't select this kind of entity.
How can it be done, preferably *without code*? (If at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a workaround by accident.
Just add a new view that queries for the node bundle that the vote is attached to. No go to "Advanced" and add a relationship to "Rate" such that the relationship is required and not restricted to the current user. Don't apply any averaging or summing. Like that, it will spit out every node several times, once for every vote cast.